# Calling another action after one is completed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux Thunk.

I got an async operation (updating message to db), and I want to wait for it to complete and then get the updated messages array from the db.

I tried:

```
const handleWriteMessage = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault()

await dispatch(
  writeMessage({
    sender: data.sender,
    subject: data.subject,
    receiver: data.receiver,
    message: data.message,
    created: date
  })
)
dispatch(getMessages())
}
```

But it doesn't mind the `await` and runs `getMessages()` immediately when `handleWriteMessage` is called.
I tried to do it in the action itself after it's completed:

```
axios
.post('http://localhost:4000/api/messages/writeMessage', msg, config)
.then((res) => {
  getMessages()
  dispatch({
    type: WRITE_MESSAGE_SUCCESS
  })
})
```

But it's not working too.

What am I missing?

Comment: `writeMessage` should return a function that returns a promise: `const writeMessage => arg => dispatch => {return promise here}`

Answer (score 0):

It seem that `handleWriteMessage` should not by `async`, it **must** return function that will accept `dispatch` and may execute `async` function, see redux-thunk [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation).

See snippet below and its output.

```js
var thunk = createThunkMiddleware();
var log = (state = [], action) => state.concat(action.message || action.type);
var store = Redux.createStore(log, [], Redux.applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));

(async() => {
  store.dispatch(asyncAC('async message 1.a'))
    .then(() => asyncAC('async message 1.b'))
    .then(store.dispatch);

  store.dispatch(syncAC('sync 1'));

  await store.dispatch(asyncAC('await async message 2.a'));

  store.dispatch(syncAC('sync 2'));

  store.dispatch(asyncAC('await async message 3.a'))
    .then(() => store.dispatch(asyncAC('then async message 3.b')));

})();

function syncAC(m) {
  return {
    type: 'log',
    message: m
  }
}

function asyncAC(m) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, syncAC(m)))
      .then(dispatch);
  }
}




// redux-thunk itself
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
  return function(_ref) {
    var dispatch = _ref.dispatch,
      getState = _ref.getState;
    return function(next) {
      return function(action) {
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
          return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
        }

        return next(action);
      };
    };
  };
}
// logger middleware
function logger({
  getState
}) {
  return next => action => {
    console.log('will dispatch', action)

    // Call the next dispatch method in the middleware chain.
    const returnValue = next(action)

    console.log('state after dispatch', getState())

    // This will likely be the action itself, unless
    // a middleware further in chain changed it.
    return returnValue
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@4.0.5/dist/redux.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But i'm really lost in understating all this. with MobX it's so much simpler.
Can you please write me in code how I should change handleWriteMessage?

Comment: my apologies, my first opinion was not fully correct, perhaps you may try to change `writeMessage` action creator implementation (compare `syncAC` vs. ` asyncAC` action creators) and keep `handleWriteMessage` almost as is.